# How can I aggregate date by fixed daily hour in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading the date histogram https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html, it shows how to aggregate based on intervals like month, hour etc.

But I have a requirement to aggregate them based on the daily hour. For example, I'd like to aggregate the date on 8am everyday in a week. It needs to aggregate all document happens between 8:00am to 8:59am from Monday to Sunday. The response should give me 7 buckets (one for each day in the week).

The response may look like. If I query one month data ( assume there are 4 weeks in this month ), the Monday bucket will include the sum of data between 8am to 9am on 4 Mondays in the month.

```json
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key_as_string" : "MONDAY 8am",
          "key" : 1641254400000,
          "doc_count" : 5
        },
        {
          "key_as_string" : "TUESDAY 8am",
          "key" : 1641254400000,
          "doc_count" : 5
        }
        ...
        {
          "key_as_string" : "SUNDAY 8am",
          "key" : 1641254400000,
          "doc_count" : 5
        }
```

Is there any way to achieve that in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Just to clarify : You want to aggregate data only between 8am to 8:59 am. In that case would an aggregation with filter work ? Something along the lines of https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html

Comment: I mean aggregate based on day in a week. For example, it gives me 8am bucket for every Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday ... Sunday

Comment: Just to understand , sorry again.So the aggregates between 9am and 7:59 aggregated (say sales of an item as of 8 AM on Monday will give sales between 8 AM Sunday to 7:59 on Monday)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this with ES. The simplest is to make a runtime mapping that contains the weekday as a term.
Aggregate on that and subaggregate by the hour with hard bounds for your required time. I havent tried this with real data, so pls tweak as necessary.

```
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "weekday": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": "
          long date = doc['date'].value.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
          ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of('Z'));
          String format = "EEEE";
          DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
          emit(formatter.format(zdt));
      "
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "weekday": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "weekday"
      },
      "aggs" : {
         "hourly" : {
            "date_histogram" : {"field" : "date", "calendar_interval" : "hour", "hard_bounds" : {"min" : 8, "max" : 9}}
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```